# Error: Cannot find module 'socket.io' when trying to run a simple server js file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Here is my server.js file I am trying to run using `node server.js`:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket-io')(http); //also tried socket.io instead of socket-io

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
console.log('User Online');

    socket.on('canvas-data', (data) => {
        socket.broadcast.emit('canvas-data', data);

    })
})

    var server_port = process.env.YOUR_PORT || process.env.PORT || 5000;
    http.listen(server_port, () => {
        console.log("Started on : " + server_port);
})
```

And here is the full error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:311
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\rami_\OneDrive\Skola\Utbildning\White board\server\node_modules\socket-io\index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" 
entry
at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:303:19)
at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:516:18)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:867:27)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\rami_\OneDrive\Skola\Utbildning\White board\server\server.js:3:10)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\rami_\\OneDrive\\Skola\\Utbildning\\White board\\server\\node_modules\\socket-io\\package.json',
  requestPath: 'socket-io'
}
```

I have run `npm install socket-io` and inside the node_modules folder I can see a folder named `socket-io`.

Comment: it's `sockt.io` not `socket-io`

Comment: `socket-io` package has nothing in it so you need to use `socket.io` then post whatever error you get back here.  run this: `npm uninstall socket-io; npm install socket.io`

Comment: to make sure socket.io is installed and served successfully try to get the socket.io client lib using this link `<your-server-ip>/socket.io/socket.io.js` in browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong package name, it is [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io), change the require to `require('socket.io')` and re-install it with npm, you're trying to use a  [deprecated package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket-io).